# Select Row under the one clicked

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

Can someone tell me how can I select the Row under the one on which I Click the Button ?

```
<asp:Button ID="btnmoveup" runat="server" Text="/\" OnCommand="MoveButton_Clicked"
                                    CommandName="UP" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProjectID") + ";"+Eval("Priority")%>'/>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <asp:Button ID="btnmovedown" runat="server" Text="\/" OnCommand="MoveButton_Clicked"
                                    CommandName="DOWN" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ProjectID") + ";"+Eval("Priority")%>' />
```

The code behind:

```
protected void MoveButton_Clicked(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
string[] arguments = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] {';'});
string pid1;
int prior;
pid1 = arguments[0];
prior = int.Parse(arguments[1]);
```

This Gives me the Priority and ProjectID of the Row in which I clicked the button.

How can I get the Priority and Project of the Row below this ? 
The Rows are in the repeater control.

Comment: What kind of row?  Client side table row? Server side table row? Gridview row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your `CommandArgument` to `<%# Container.ItemIndex %>`.

Then in your `Clicked` event, you can do something like:

```
int clickedIndex = int.Parse(e.CommandArgument);
int selectIndex = clickedIndex + 1; // or -1 depending on the button clicked.
var dataItem = (YourDataType)(yourRepeater.Items[selectIndex].DataItem);
var priority = dataItem.Priority;
var projectID = dataItem.ProjectID;
```

Alternatively you can bind the priority and project ID to hidden fields in the repeater, and use `yourRepeater.Items[selectIndex].FindControl('yourHiddenFieldId').Text` or similar.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but what if I want both ? Rowid and the priority of the row below/above and the one I clicked as i want to swap the values

Comment: You can access the clicked row's values in exactly the same way as the below row's values. You'd just use `yourRepeater.Items[clickedIndex]` instead of `yourRepeater.Items[selectIndex]`.

Comment: Hi, in this case what should I have for (yourDataType) ? since my repeater contains many different dataype ?

Comment: If it has many different datatypes, how do you know each one has a ProjectID and a Priority property?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/UiX3gYR2 this is what my Repeater looks like! and my projectId is varchar and priority an Integer show what should I have in place of (YourDataTpye) ?